# Magnolia 5.4.7 Change Column Sortation

Tags: java, vaadin, magnolia

i want to change the default sortation of a `Column` so that it only sorts alphabetically on the first tier and sorts by the jcr node on the rest of the tiers.

I honestly don't know where to start. First i tried to extend the existing `TreePresenterDefinition`, but soon i realised that was the wrong way.
Currently i try to extend an `PropertyColumnDefinition` and write my own `ColumnFormatter`.

Anyone can give me a direction to look into?

Wishes,
Hellfiend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you should be touching *Containers*, for instance one may extend *AbstractJcrContainer* for your application and set the sorting as you wish there basically one may follow this way; (Vaadin way)

```
  IndexedContainer ic = new IndexedContainer() {
            @Override
            public Collection<?> getSortableContainerPropertyIds() {
                // Default implementation allows sorting only if the property
                // type can be cast to Comparable
                return getContainerPropertyIds();
            }
        };

        ic.setItemSorter(new DefaultItemSorter(new Comparator<Object>() {
                public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {                

            }
        }));
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks! I currently added a column with the prefix of each node and wanted to sort that one alphabetically...Shame sorting doesn't seem to work at all in the treeview. If i get more Time i will try your way, which seems way more clean in my opinion.

Comment: Theres is not enough time for such a deep change, but it would seem to be the correct way.